# Can we add multiple models and export it to qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I have created a model and exported it to `qml`. Now `qml` list elements gets updated from this model but I need a `nestedlist`. On click of the `outerlist` element inner list gets opened and the `innerlist` is a separate model. Any examples ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the [TreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html) control. There are a few examples in the Examples section of Qt Creator.